# Order with amsalpha

Tags: bibtex

I am using `amsalpha` with `bibtex`. It seems to me that the order of the citation is alphabetical with respect to the keys.

Would it be possible to change it to alphabetical with respect to the authors?

I give an example. Supposes we have

> [CD13] Cat and Dog, ...
>
> [CH13] Cow and Horse, ...
>
> [CL13] Cat and Lion, ...

I would rather have

> [CD13] Cat and Dog, ...
>
> [CL13] Cat and Lion, ...
>
> [CH13] Cow and Horse, ...

Thanks! :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The rationale is that a reader will look for the label, rather than the authors.

Comment: cmhughes: Thank you! :) @egreg sorry I am not sure I understand

Comment: @MrWoody When the reader wants to look up a reference, he knows the label, say CD13, from the text. Thus, it is better the bibliography is sorted by labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think it is a good idea to sort by author names. If someone reads your text and finds a citation label CD13, she quickly wants to find that in the bibliography, so the bibliography should be sorted by labels.

That being said, for purely didactical reasons your scheme can be implemented as follows:

1. Make a copy of `amsalpha.bst`, say `amsalpha2.bst`, and place it somewhere where BibTeX can find it.
2. Open `amsalpha2.bst` with an editor, and locate the function `FUNCTION {presort}`
3. Comment out the four lines as indicated:

   ```
   FUNCTION {presort}
   { calc.label
     %sort.label   %% commented out
     %"    "       %% commented out
     %*            %% commented out
     type$ "book" =
     type$ "inbook" =
     or
       'author.editor.sort
       { type$ "proceedings" =
       'editor.organization.sort
       { type$ "manual" =
           'author.organization.sort
           'author.sort
         if$
       }
         if$
       }
     if$
     %*              %% commented out
     "    "
     *
     year field.or.null sortify
     *
     "    "
     *
     title field.or.null
     sort.format.title
     *
     #1 entry.max$ substring$
     'sort.key$ :=
   }
   ```

That way, the author names will be the top sort criterion if present, not the labels. You can now use `amsalpha2` as your bibliography style.

Comment: There is a small bug in this. If you have multiple entries that should have the 'a' and 'b' suffixed added (for example, [Ant13a],[Ant13b]), but they happen to get separated  due to another author having a name in between those two, it is possible to end up with two [Ant13] in the bibliography.